# Constexpr friend functions in MSVC

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, constexpr

I'm trying to define constexpr friend operator in template. I got a compiler error when trying to instantiate this operator in non-constexpr context. If I define the very same operator as a template class member of as a free template function, it works fine.

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    T Value;

    // error
    friend constexpr bool operator== (const A& l, const A& r)
    {
        return l.Value == r.Value;
    }

    // ok
    constexpr bool operator!= (const A& r) const
    {
        return Value != r.Value;
    }
};

// ok
template <typename T> constexpr bool
operator< (const A<T>& l, const A<T>& r)
{
    return l.Value < r.Value;
}

#include <string>
int main ()
{
    A<std::string> s;
    bool ret = (s < s, s == s, s != s);
}
```

The error I've got is

```
<source>(7): error C3615: constexpr function 'operator ==' cannot result in a constant expression

<source>(9): note: failure was caused by call of undefined function or one not declared 'constexpr'

<source>(9): note: see usage of 'std::operator =='

<source>(8): note: while compiling class template member function 'bool operator ==(const A<std::string> &,const A<std::string> &)'

<source>(29): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'A<std::string>' being compiled
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/d-Y2fX)

Is this 'friend' discrimination is a requirement of the standard or a compiler bug?

Comment: No error with gcc or clang, probably an msvc bug.

Comment: It should not compile with GCC or Clang, unless they have extended the standard with `constexpr` overloads of `std::string`'s comparison operators. In the [C++ reference](https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) there are no `constexpr` overloads.

Comment: @j00hi why does msvc only complain about the friend operator? Make it a non-friend and it's compiles. Compiler conspiracy?

Comment: MSVC seems to be more picky about friend operator declarations, at least in templated types. See my [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54866446/387023) for the fix.

Comment: @j00hi A constexpr function template instantiation that fails to satisfy the constexpr requirements is **not** an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[dcl.constexpr] says this:

> If the instantiated template specialization of a constexpr function template or member function of a class template would fail to satisfy the requirements for a constexpr function or constexpr constructor, that specialization is still a constexpr function or constexpr constructor, even though a call to such a function cannot appear in a constant expression.

So it's perfectly OK to instantiate your class template with `std::string`, and your comparison functions are still `constexpr`, though calls to them are *not* constant expressions (check this by declaring `ret` `constexpr`). Marking these functions `constexpr` won't buy you anything at all (in this instantiation), but it's perfectly legal.

The standard then goes on to say

> If no specialization of the template would satisfy the requirements for a constexpr function or constexpr constructor when considered as a non-template function or constructor, the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

This doesn't seem to be applicable to your case however, as instantiations with e.g. built-in types do satisfy `constexpr` requirements.

The compilation error of MSVC doesnt't seem justified. It looks like a bug in the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the error message which you got can be quite misleading or at least confusing.
The problem with your code is an incorrect `friend`-declaration.

Declaring an operator inside a templated struct as being a `friend` makes it a free function, just like `operator<` in your example, hence the two parameters instead of only one parameter like it is the case for `operator!=` as you have declared it in your example. If you would declare `operator<` as a friend of `struct A`, the correct way to do so would be:

```
template <typename  X>
friend constexpr bool operator< (const A<X>& l, const A<X>& r);
```

The same goes for `operator==`. The proper declaration would be:

```
template <typename X>
friend constexpr bool operator== (const A<X>& l, const A<X>& r)
{
    return l.Value == r.Value;
}
```

i.e. WITH `template <typename X>` which you left out in your problematic example and therefore, didn't compile. Your original `operator==` declaration would not result in a proper friend-free-function-operator for `struct A`.

The complete code listing including the fix would be the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    T Value;

    // no error anymore
    template <typename X>
    friend constexpr bool operator== (const A<X>& l, const A<X>& r)
    {
        return l.Value == r.Value;
    }

    // ok
    constexpr bool operator!= (const A& r) const
    {
        return Value != r.Value;
    }
};
```

You could also declare it like follows

```
template <typename T>
friend constexpr bool operator== (const A<T>& l, const A<T>& r)
```

with `T` instead of `X` but it is actually the same, since the inner `T` overrides the outer `T`.

Comment: How do you explain that non-constexpr friend compiles?

https://godbolt.org/z/rSKTeA